# Sitecore Pipeline Error

Tags: exception, sitecore, sitecore6

Has anyone seen this error before in Sitecore?

```
  Could not get pipeline: hasPresentation (domain: )

[InvalidOperationException: Could not get pipeline: hasPresentation (domain: )]
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +460
Sitecore.Pipelines.HasPresentation.HasPresentationPipeline.Run(Item item) +149
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.RenderTreecrumbGo(HtmlTextWriter output, Item item) +147
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.RenderTreecrumb(Item item) +233
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +1103
```

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the information at https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/webConfig/660_121015.aspx the `HasPresentation` pipeline was introduced in **Sitecore CMS 6.6.0 rev. 121015 (Update-1)**.

The exception you are experiencing is thrown when the pipeline can not be found. It looks like your **Sitecore.Kernel.dll** version doesn't match your configuration version.

Were you trying to upgrade **Sitecore** version? Which version of **Sitecore** dll are in the **bin** directory of your web application?